# How can I change background color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change my background color with slider value. But I want to select colors from my `PickColor()` method. By the way, I am learning new UI system. I dont so much know how it works

```
public Slider bgColorSldr;
public Image background;

private Color32 color;

void PickColor(int colorNo)//My colors
    {
        switch (colorNo)
        {
            case 0:
                color = new Color32(0, 0, 0, 255);
                break;
            case 1:
                color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255);
                break;
            case 2:
                color = new Color32(255, 0, 0, 255);
                break;
            case 3:
                color = new Color32(0, 255, 0, 255);
                break;
            case 4:
                color = new Color32(0, 0 , 255, 255);
                break;
            case 5:
                color = new Color32(255, 255, 0, 255);
                break;
            case 6:
                color = new Color32(0, 255, 255, 255);
                break;
            case 7:
                color = new Color32(255, 0, 255, 255);
                break;
            case 8:
                color = new Color32(192, 192, 192, 255);
                break;
            case 9:
                color = new Color32(128, 128, 128, 255);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Surely your colors are made up of ARGB?

Comment: So what's the problem? You assign `color` a value but don't do anything from there.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore this not about microsoft library. This is unity3d question, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand your question fully, but I try to help you.

1. Set your Slider like this. Max value is 10, because you have 10 color. And choose `Whole Numbers` it is important, 
   [image]
2. You have public ChangeColor method like this. Put this method any your object and add it to your slider's `On Value Changed()` method.

   ```
   public void ChangeColor()
       {
           PickColor ((int)bgColorSldr.value);
           background.color = color;
       }
   ```